# sobrescribir desde una subclase un método de una clase abstracta

Tags: java, poo

Siempre que queramos sobrescribir desde una subclase un método de una clase abstracta, ¿Este método tiene que ser obligatoriamente abstracto o se puede sobrescribir sobre un método normal de una clase abstracta?.

Gracias.

Comment: Si tuvieras un ejemplo de tu duda, quiza te podrias ayudar mejor

Answer (score 3):

## Regla general

De manera general, podemos sobre-escribir un método que no sea declarado como estático o final en la clase ancestro.

## ¿Se puede sobre-escribir solo los métodos abstractos de una clase abstracta?

Para responder específicamente a tu pregunta: para sobre-escribir un método, este no necesariamente tiene por que haber sido declarado como abstracto en la super-clase.

## De nuevo a lo general

Generalizando un poco en java, cuando escribes una clase que hereda de otra, los métodos de una clase ancestro pueden **sobre-escribirse** (si son métodos de instancia) y **ocultarse** (si son métodos de la clase, también llamados estáticos).

Cuando escribes una clase de la que otras heredarán, puedes evitar que un método sea sobre-escrito **final** (no puede ocultarse por un descendiente). También puedes declarar algún método como **abstracto**, lo que significa que a esta altura de la jerarquía, se desconoce completamente su implementación. La clase que contenga un método abstracto debe ser declarada, a su vez, como abstracta.

Cuando heredas de una clase abstracta, puedes o no sobre-escribir todos los métodos abstractos, pero si no lo haces, debes declarar la sub-clase a su vez como abstracta. No pueden crearse instancias de una clase abstracta.

Para terminar, quiero ahondar un poco en la parte de

## ocultar y sobre-escribir.

Cuando en una clase declaras un método como estático, las sub-clases no pueden sobre-escribirlo, solamente ocultarlo.

Hay una diferencia importante entre sobre-escribir y ocultar. Cuando sobre-escribes un método, para el mundo exterior es como si el método de la clase ancestro dejara de existir totalmente, el nuevo método será llamado siempre, sin importar el tipo de la variable sobre la que se realice la invocación.

En cambio, cuando ocultas un método estático, ambos siguen *existiendo* para el mundo exterior, y el método que se llamará en tiempo de corrida se determinará según la visibilidad de la clase (o ell tipo de la variable) sobre la que se invoque.

Veamos con un ejemplo, adaptado de la [documentación oficial sobre sobre-escribir y ocultar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html). Supongamos que tenemos dos clases:

```
public class Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("Método estático en Animal");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Método de instancia en Animal");
    }
}
```

La segunda clase, que es sub-clase de animal, es llamada `Cat`:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("Método estático en Cat");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Método de instancia en Cat");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        Animal.testClassMethod();
        myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

La clase `Cat` sobre-escribe el método de instancia declarado en `Animal` y oculta el método estático declarado en `Animal`. El método principal en esta clase crea una instancia de `Cat` e invoca el método `testClassMethod()` en la clase y `testInstanceMethod()` en la instancia.

La salida del programa es la siguiente:

```
Método estático en Animal
Método de instancia en Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede sobre uno "normal" como dices, pero no es obligatorio. Los abstractos hay que implementarlos **obligatoriamente**.

EDITO:
A menos que sea también abstracta como dice @SJuan76 . Yo había entendido que no era el caso. Puedes saber más leyendo [la documentación al respecto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Comment: Bueno, hay que implementarlos obligatoriamente siempre que la subclase no sea también abstracta. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Requisitos para sobrescribir métodos

- Un método de instancia solo puede sobrescribirse si la subclase los hereda (método `public`). Si un método no se puede heredar (método `private`), no se puede sobrescribir.
- Un método declarado `final` no puede ser sobrescrito. Un método `private` es implícitamente `final`.
- Un método declarado `static` no se puede sobrescribir, pero se puede volver a declarar.
- Un método constructor no se puede sobrescribir.

---

Por consiguiente.

> *¿Un método de una clase abstracta tiene que ser obligatoriamente abstracto?*

No necesariamente.

> *¿Se puede sobrescribir sobre un método normal de una clase abstracta?*

Sí. Mientras no sea `final` ni `private`.